# how to substitute and print column in perl just like in awk

Tags: bash, perl, awk, replace, substitution

I have this bash/awk code to deal with hosts

```
$ echo 'the.pattern to change' | awk '{sub(/the./,"")}{print $1}'
pattern
```

I would need to replace awk by perl.
Any idea how to replace the second part of the statement by perl oneliner?

Comment: why do you need to replace awk with perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
echo 'the.pattern to change' | perl -aE '$F[0] =~ s/the\.//; say $F[0]'
```

**Output:**

```
pattern
```

Comment: You have missed `-n`

Comment: @mkHun:  `-n` adds a while loop around the code, it is not mandatory in this case, there is just a string in input. But you're right if we have to deal with a file.

Comment: I have executed your line but it didn't give the any result. Because we are not passing the data.  If I added -n switch it is giving the result.

Answer (score 2):

One more way:

`echo 'the.pattern to change' | perl -lpe 's/the\.//;$_=(/[^ ]+/g)[0];'`

[image: command execution example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Perl one liner with split function.

We need to split the character using `the.` and `space`. So you can use the RegEx inside the split function.

```
echo 'the.pattern to change' | perl -aF"/the\.|\s/" -ne 'print $F[1],"\n";'
```

`-a` auto split mode

```
echo 'the.pattern to change' | perl -ane '$F[0]=~s/the\.//; print $F[0],"\n";'
```

Comment: This is as close as you can get to `awk` with Perl. I don't understand the downvote, either.

Comment: @reinierpost I downvoted,since it doesn't do the same thing at all. Achieving the same result doesn't mean the commands do the same thing. OP isn't splitting the fields on `the.`, it works completely differently than the awk command. An awk equivelent of this would be `awk -F'the\.|\s' '{print $1}'`. A closer perl command to OP would be `perl -lne 's/the\.//;print +(split /\s+/)[0]'`

Comment: @123 Take a look at my previous edits. First I have post as such what your are mentioned in your comment (Not exactly). Then I gave a another solution for the same result.

Comment: @mkHun: probably better to replace both solutions with a correct one, namely one that substitutes in the unsplit string and then prints the first field